# Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, character-encoding, readfile

I have this code to download a files.

```
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"도망자_PLAN_B.English.xml\"" );
header('Content-Type: "application/xml"; charset="utf-8"');
readfile('http://xxx.xxx.x.xx/www/path/to/file/2015/12/도망자_PLAN_B.English.xml');
```

after I downloed the file and open it I found this error instead of xml code

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  readfile(http://xxx.xxx.x.xx/www/path/to/file/2015/12/도망자_PLAN_B.English.xml): failed to open  stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
in <b>C:/path/to/file/functions.php</b> on line <b>452</b>
```

I know is the problem with the ward `도망자`.
How to make it download the file with the same name?

Comment: add `header('Content-Type: "application/xml"; charset="utf-8"');` at top of your file and try again

Comment: possibly the local filesystem + OS + PHP (any of those or in combination)  have problems with those characters too. I 'solved' this once on some MS-OS by using utf8_decode() on the filename. I cannot advice it as a general solution though... PS your problem lies within the readfile(), the headers won't help since the file cannot be read.